# Remote control ceiling fan won’t turn on

Tags: ceiling-fan

I installed a Home Decorators Kensgrove 64 in. LED Espresso Bronze Ceiling Fan w/Remote.
Followed all instructions for pairing the remote to the fan. Installed brand new batteries in remote. When turned on, the remote will turn the light on, and the dimmer control works. When I turn the fan on it starts to turn (calibrate) like the manual says it will, but then nothing. We can’t get the fan to turn on once it’s done calibrating. Any ideas what the problem might be?
Thanks.

Comment: did you change the DIP switch position ?

Comment: Try the calibration again.  Turn off the power to the fan and remove the batteries to the remote.  Turn power to the fan on after about 10 min. then load the batteries.  Do the calibration.

Answer (score 1):

Use wall mounted regular switch. Do not use a dimmer.

Set the DIP switches. Turn on dip 1 and dip 3 on the handheld remote but do the same on the receiver mounted above the fan

Comment: These fans remotes do not have DIP switches.